# Can we withdraw lamports from a PDA which contains data?

Tags: solana-program, rust, pda, lamports

U cannot withdraw lamports from a pda that contains data , u can only withdraw lamports from pda or normal account which is owned by system program and it should not contain any data at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transfer SOL from a PDA owned by your program:

```
let src = &mut ctx.accounts.pda_account.to_account_info();
**src.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? = src
    .lamports()
    .checked_sub(lamports)
    .ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidArgument)?;

let dst = &mut ctx.accounts.account_b.to_account_info();
**dst.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? = dst
    .lamports()
    .checked_add(lamports)
    .ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidArgument)?;
```

Comment: I have tried doing it but the accounts did not update even though it didn't gave any error

Comment: @NagaprasadVr can you post some code?